# How to set a static default timezone in amcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts, amcharts4

I have a little DB with timestamped data over several days. My problem is that I live in GMT+2 (CEST) and that my graph's dateaxis (x) is offset wrongly.
As shown in the image the time is shown on the hour's 00:00 (day switch and as such shown as the new day) and 12:00. But in reality the tooltip tells that the data is actually from 6 hours later.
[image: wrong offset graph]

I use the below code to generate the graph and load the data using php and the `getTemperatures` function in the required format.

```
am4core.ready(function() {

  // Themes begin
  am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
  // Themes end

  var chart = am4core.create("chart", am4charts.XYChart);
  chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
  chart.data = <?=json_encode(getTemperatures())?>;

  // Create axes
  var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
  dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0.5;
  dateAxis.renderer.labels.template.location = 0.5;
  dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 60;

  dateAxis.dateFormats.setKey("second", "HH:mm:ss");
  dateAxis.dateFormats.setKey("minute", "HH:mm");
  dateAxis.dateFormats.setKey("hour", "HH:mm");
  dateAxis.dateFormats.setKey("day", "dt");

  dateAxis.periodChangeDateFormats.setKey("minute", "HH:mm");
  dateAxis.periodChangeDateFormats.setKey("hour", "dt");
  dateAxis.periodChangeDateFormats.setKey("day", "MMMM dt");
  dateAxis.periodChangeDateFormats.setKey("month", "MMMM");
  dateAxis.baseInterval = {
    "timeUnit": "second",
    "count": 30
  };

  var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

  // Create series
  var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
  series.dataFields.valueY = "temperature";
  series.dataFields.dateX = "atDate";
  series.tooltipText = "{dateX.formatDate('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}\n {temperature}"

  series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";

  chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
  chart.cursor.snapToSeries = series;
  chart.cursor.xAxis = dateAxis;

  //chart.scrollbarY = new am4core.Scrollbar();
  chart.scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();

  });
```

How can I set a standard/default timezone as to the incoming data should be interpreted. I really don't want to encode timezone information into my
data as that would add more storage requirements for the DB.

Comment: You can use [`timezoneOffset`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/dateformatter/#timezoneOffset_property) setting for that.

Comment: @martynasma that just broke the code when I added `chart.dateFormatter.timezoneOffset(120);`

Comment: Because it's a property, not a method. `chart.dateFormatter.timezoneOffset = 120`